# Unable to target ID via Javascript

Tags: javascript

My mission is to tweak this website https://www.mintpal.com/market/XC/BTC# so it will show a different color for the value if it sees "buy orders" over 2.00000000 BTC.

As an example, you check the image https://i.stack.imgur.com/I8NlK.png ( the example worked because i targeted them each one separately with "#buyTotal-0-00126011" and so on.

I only want that td#buyTotal pane to be changed.

I tried to target it with the following:

```
   1 - var cell = $('td') - it works, but it changes the values globally
   2 - var cell = $('#buyTotal' + price + value.total) - not working
   3 - var cell = $('td#buyTotal') - not working.
```

The code should look similar to this in the end...

```
var cell = $('td#buyTotal')

cell.each(function() {
var cell_value = $(this).html();
if ((cell_value >= 0) && (cell_value >=2.00000000)) {
    $(this).css({'background' : '#FF0000'});   
} else if ((cell_value >= 3) && (cell_value >=5.00000000)) {
    $(this).css({'background' : '#FF0000'});
} else if (cell_value >= 8.00000000) {
    $(this).css({'background' : '#FF0000'});
}
});
```

You can also access this as a shortcut ' mintpal.com/assets/js/market.js '

If i omitted something, please let me know. Thanks....

Edit: I'm only playing with the code inspector/console on the website. What i want is extremely simple. It's just that i cannot target the id. I updated the photo also.

Comment: You omitted the markup itself. Links to external sites are fine, but the actual code in question must be posted here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will require regex.

```
var cells = document.querySelectorAll('*[id^="buyTotal"]');
for(var i = 0; i < cells.length; i++) {
  if(cells[i].innerHTML > 2) { cells[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red'; }
}
```

Comment: This is the right selector, but you should convert the content to a _Number_ as it's always best to compare two things of the same type.

Comment: What @PaulS. said is right-- you should always be casting. My answer was to show you how to grab and iterate through a list of elements that all start with a specific id string. What you do after that is for another discussion.